# Prestashop 1.6 Several module config pages

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am looking for way how to split my prestashop 1.6 module configuration page to several pages, because it's too long in current state. Is there something like menu/tabs helper? I will be glad for any recommendetions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these [Using the HelperOptions class](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperOptions+class), [Using Bootstrap](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+Bootstrap) (check below in **Navigation, tabs and menus**: nav, nav-tabs classes) and maybe this [Using jQuery and jQueryUI](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+jQuery+and+jQueryUI) will helpful.